# Enable Audio only in tokbox api

Tags: opentok, tokbox

i am using tokbox api integration for conference calls between two people.however ,sometimes based on user choice in my web application,i want to have only audio enabled in the tokbox session.
Is there a way to do so.
i am using api calls to generate a session id and javascript workaround to generate a token,unable to use sdk as GAE doesnt support it.

Inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to disable publishing video, which results in audio only. The code is `publisher.publishVideo(false)`. See the docs for Publisher for more information: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#publishVideo

Which language Server SDK is not working on GAE to generate tokens? It's a very bad idea to generate your tokens in JS on the client because your API Secret will be sent in the clear to anyone who visits your page.

Comment: Java GAE - Fails at dependency Jars-when i manually added all jars, an errorr related to "Unable to Use HTTPS service" was thrown, as i guess Https is still not suported in GAE-is there a workaround